# How exactly thermal infrared (e.g. FLIR) cameras image methane leaks? Are they measuring a temperature difference or an emissivity difference or...?

Tags: physical-chemistry, ir-spectroscopy, optical-properties

The story [Infrared camera shows the impact of vehicle emissions](http://www.vision-systems.com/articles/print/volume-22/issue-5/departments/snapshots/may-2017-snapshots-boston-dynamics-robot-autonomous-vehicles-infrared-imaging.html) says:

> In an effort to visually demonstrate the potentially fatal impacts of air pollution, FLIR Systems (Wilsonville, OR, USA; [www.flir.com](http://www.flir.com)) has released a new video containing footage captured by FLIR infrared cameras that shows vehicle emissions and the resulting pollution issues.

> [...] To accomplish this, FLIR used its GF320 infrared camera to capture video of the emissions. This camera features a 320 x 240 cooled InSb infrared detector with a spectral response of 3.2 to 3.4 μm. Designed specifically for gas leak detection and electrical inspection, the camera also embeds GPS data into the image, allowing workers to pinpoint the location of the leak or hot spot.

Wikipedia says [InSb is a narrow-gap semiconductor with an energy band gap of 0.17 eV at 300 K and 0.23 eV at 80 K](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indium_antimonide#Physical_properties) and a focal plane array can image light with a wavelengths in the 1 to 5 micron range. They are often cooled to reduce dark current for better sensitivity. In this case it sounds like they've added an interference filter to selectively pass 3.2 to 3.4 microns.

My question is about what it is they are really imaging here. It is true that gases such as CO2 and methane have strong IR bands, this is why they are important greenhouse gasses. Are they measuring a temperature difference or an emissivity difference or light scattering or absorption or...? How does this technique actually work?

- Youtube [Seeing Air Pollution with FLIR Thermal Imaging Cameras](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=514Uh6Mq_Cs)
- Youtube [How Dying Gas Wells Are Making One Company Rich](https://youtu.be/6c-WCg2Y7sE?t=487) FLIR imaging of methane leaks from gas wells

[image]

**above:** Image from [this article](http://www.vision-systems.com/articles/print/volume-22/issue-5/departments/snapshots/may-2017-snapshots-boston-dynamics-robot-autonomous-vehicles-infrared-imaging.html).

Comment: As far as I know, the relevant IR absorption of CO$_2$ is due to the bending motion at about 600 cm$^{-1}$ - and it does overlap with the heat radiation of the Earth. For methane, it's the peak at 1300 cm$^{-1}$, the motion can be seen [here](http://www2.ess.ucla.edu/~schauble/MoleculeHTML/CH4_html/CH4_page.html)

Comment: Methane does have a strong absorbance in the 3-4 micron range: https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74828&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=1

Comment: This paper discusses methane detection by FLIR cameras in detail. It is indeed based on absorbance of the background IR in the 3.2-3.4 micron window: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/acs.est.6b03906

Comment: @Andrew hmm... I wonder if high absorbance also means high re-emittance of the same light? If it's at the same temperature as the surrounding material, how can it be brighter or darker?

Comment: I wouldn’t necessarily assume it’s the same temp as surroundings, but whatever the temp, the re-emission will be much broader spectrum than the absorbance, so there is still a significant decrease in observed transmission at the measured wavelengths.

Comment: Slight correction - I read more of the paper, and they say that both the emissivity of the methane and the absorbance of background are important contributors to the signal depending on the situation. A hot methane plume is visible against a cold sky because of the plume's higher emissivity, whereas a cold plume is best observed against high background emissions because of the absorbance of the plume. At least that's how I'm reading it. But you should read the paper yourself rather than trust my quick interpretation.

Comment: Did you read the paper? I think it provides much better info that you'll ever get from an answer here.

Comment: @Andrew the goal of Stack Exchange questions is to facilitate the generation of Stack Exchange answers. That's why link-only answers are so poorly received. If you think the answer is in that paper, one way you could demonstrate your confidence in that would be to post a short answer, linking to it, and explaining and quoting the bits you feel do the job.

Comment: Sorry, I should have been more clear. My intended point was that if it is important to you to have an answer to this question, you have sufficient information in the paper to write a self-answer. That seems much more effective than repeatedly bountying a question that continues to receive little interest.

Comment: @Andrew noted, but bounties are *exactly* the thing to use when there is "little interest", and I simply like [bountying](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/546030/217285)! All it takes is a single person to take an interest to write an answer.

Comment: Fair point. If you don't mind waiting for someone else to write an answer, that's your choice and I shouldn't be critical of it.

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

The cameras you are asking about are called [optical gas imaging (OGI) cameras](https://www.flir.ca/products/gfx320), they are not [thermographic cameras](https://www.flir.ca/browse/professional-tools/thermography-cameras/) per se, but are a modified kind instead.
However, both use the same principles to actually detect the infrared light, the key difference is the incident radiation is filtered to allow only the wavelengths that interact with the methane gas plume (or other analyte gas) to interact with the camera sensor.
Thermographic cameras could be configured to take both kinds of images since the principle of their operation is essentially the same, but they are usually separate devices for practical reasons like cost, increasing image contrast, *etc.*.
In the images you provided, you can see the solid objects because they emit, reflect, and absorb infrared light across the spectrum, so they can also be seen by the OGI cameras.
However, other gases are not seen because the IR light they absorb is filtered out.
Finally, a temperature difference must exist between the plume of gas being imaged and the background scenery because otherwise the amount of infrared radiation emitted will be equal to the amount absorbed by the gas, following [Kirchoff's Law of thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation).

## Detailed Answer

### Methane detection colour analogy

Cameras for visible light discriminate between colours  by placing a filter before the sensor so that only one colour (i.e., red, green, or blue) is absorbed by the sensor at any given pixel.
The sum of the RGB signal reproduces the subject's colour.
Although we cannot see them with our eyes, infrared light has different "colours" that can be discriminated by a camera sensor with the appropriate absorption range, filters, *etc.*.
Visible light has different colours depending on the energy (i.e., wavelength or frequency) of the light:
red light has a longer wavelength (lower energy and frequency) than green, and blue, respectively.
We can see an apple is red when the green and blue light in white backlight are absorbed by its skin while the red light is reflected into our eyes (or camera).
In the same way, we can see the infrared "colour" of different objects by observing the infrared light they absorb.
[image: FTIR spectrum of CO2]
**Figure 1** [FTIR spectrum of carbon dioxide from NIST.](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C124389&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=1#IR-SPEC)
[image]
**Figure 2** [FTIR spectrum of methane from NIST](https://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C74828&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=1#IR-SPEC), notice the lack of overlap between this spectrum and that of carbon dioxide (above).

Each arrangement of atoms in a molecule with different nuclear charges (i.e., polar bonds) absorbs a specific wavelength of light because the vibrations are quantum mechanical in nature.
[These vibrations are characteristic to each molecule, so we can identify them by observing which wavelengths of light they absorb.](http://www2.ess.ucla.edu/%7Eschauble/molecular_vibrations.htm)
See the above two Fourier-transformed infrared (FTIR) spectra of carbon dioxide and methane.
This is the basis of spectroscopy, which is out of the scope of this answer.
But, if we designing a sensor that can discriminate between certain wavelengths of infrared light, a camera can be made that can see how much of a particular wavelength (e.g., 3.5 μm for methane, 10.57 μm for sulfur hexafluoride) is being absorbed relative to the background.
Couple this principle to a system that can tell where the light is coming from, i.e. add pixels, add some optics to focus the light, and you have a camera.

### Optical gas imaging (OGI)

The objects in the field of view (FOV) in OGI are illuminated by the background infrared radiation emitted from the sun and all other warm objects.
This is why OGI is also called a "passive" thermal imaging technique, in contrast to "active" techniques where the scene is illuminated with an artificial light source directed at the subject.
OGI depicts the relative decrease (or increase) in the intensity $\Delta I(\lambda)$ at a certain wavelength $\lambda$ of this background radiation $I_B(\lambda)$ due to absorption (or emission) by the analyte gas with intensity $I_G(\lambda)$.
A general OGI equation (Eq. 1) for $\Delta I$ can be [derived using a radiative transfer model](https://eyecgas.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/OGI-101-%E2%80%93-OGI-Equations.pdf):

$\Delta I(\lambda) = I_b(\lambda) - I_g(\lambda) = [1 - \tau_g(\lambda)][B(T_b,\lambda) - B(T_g,\lambda)]\quad(1)$

where $\tau_g$ is the transmission coefficients of the  analyte gas, and $B(T_b,\lambda)$ and $B(T_g,\lambda)$ are the [Planck law functions for blackbody radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck%27s_law#The_law) of the background at temperature $T_b$ and the analyte gas at temperature $T_g$, respectively.

We can obtain the transmission coeffecient of the gas plume in relation to its composition, concentration, and geometry using [Beer's law](https://chem.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry_Textbook_Maps/Supplemental_Modules_(Physical_and_Theoretical_Chemistry)/Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy/Electronic_Spectroscopy_Basics/The_Beer-Lambert_Law) (Eq. 2)

$\tau_g(\lambda) = \exp[-\alpha_g(\lambda)\bar{C}_g \ell_g]\quad\quad\quad (2)$

where $\alpha_g$ is the gas's absorption coeffecient, $\bar{C}_g$ is the average concentration of the gas through the line of sight, and $\ell_g$ is the breadth of the gas plume through the line of sight.

Now we can see that the gas plume image obtained by OGI systems requires three things to be detectable:

1. Absorption (or emission) of infrared radiation in a certain band of wavelengths ($\lambda$);
2. Plume that is big enough ($\ell_g$) or concentration that is high enough ($\bar{C}_g$) to absorb (or emit) enough infrared radiation to be detected; and
3. Temperature difference $\Delta T = T_b - T_g$ that is great enough between the background and the gas plume so they absorb (or emit) different amounts of infrared radiation (Eq. 3).

Each of these three factors contribute to the overall contrast observed in the image between areas where there is a gas plume and where there is not.
The final point may be mysterious to the reader, but it is due to [Kirchhoff's law of thermal radiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_law_of_thermal_radiation).
Put simply, if the gas were the same (apparent) temperature as the object behind it (in the line of sight), then it would absorb as much infrared radiation as it was emitting, and would appear invisible to the OGI camera.
If the gas plume has a lower temperature ($T_b > T_g$), it will absorb more infrared radiation as it passes through it to the camera relative to the atmosphere around it, thus $\Delta I < 0$ and the gas plume will appear darker.
If the gas plume has a higher temperature ($T_b < T_g$), then $\Delta I > 0$ and the gas plume will appear brighter.

For more detail on OGI and its quantitative variant (QOGI), please see this [recent dissertation by Michael Nagorski out of Waterloo](https://uwspace.uwaterloo.ca/handle/10012/18931).

### Commercial OGI cameras

Teledyne FLIR LLC, the company you specifically are referring to in your question and who [appear to make the industry standard cameras](https://dx.doi.org/10.1021/acs.est.0c01285), describe the operation of their OGI and thermographic cameras and sensors in some detail in [US Patent No. 9,276,161 B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9276161B2) and [9,007,687 B2](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9007687B2).
They have invented arrays of quantum wells of indium antimonide (InSb) that are specially designed to absorb radiation as close to a strong absorption band in the gas plumes that are to be imaged.
State-of-the-art camera systems include advanced optics and filters to improve the signal-to-noise ratio, thus increasing the contrast of the acquired image. Directly from US Patent No. 9,276,161 B2:

> Generally, the camera system **100** is used for detecting a gaseous compound in the scene **106** when radiation from the scene **106** is received by the lens **104** and passed to the band pass filter **110** to limit the wavelength range of survey scene energy focused onto the FPA **108**. In one embodiment, the wavelength range is limited to 10.3 to 10.8 μm. Other wavelength ranges are also contemplated. Each sensor element of the FPA **108** generates an analog photo current value according to a photo current responsivity profile and other factors in response to an irradiance generated by the spectrally filtered scene image formed by the lens **104** at the sensor element active surface. The analog photo current values are read out from each photo sensor element and converted to corresponding digital signal values for rendering a video image frame corresponding to the digital signal values.

In the aforementioned patents they give some details on the ways they have improved upon the principles laid out above.

Comment: *Thanks & Welcome to ChemSE!* If it's absorption only, then a methane could would always appear as a simple darkening of the background behind (if thin) or big black cloud if thick. And yet, the images shown in these videos (at these times) look much more complex than that. [1](https://youtu.be/514Uh6Mq_Cs?t=70), [2](https://youtu.be/6c-WCg2Y7sE?t=498), [3](https://youtu.be/t8Lrr5LTWjw?t=147) In the third video for example, the plume from the stack is hotter than the sky behind it, not colder. In this case it seems to be radiating more strongly than the background, not absorbing light from it.

Comment: You can just invert the image to make absorption (black) look like emission (white), that is entirely a perceptual difference. Besides, the plume should appear "hotter" than the background because the methane concentration is higher coming out of the engine than it is in the atmosphere. The intensity of the image is due to the concentration of methane which is inversely proportional to the transmission of the infrared light absorbed by methane.

Comment: I should also clarify that the image has almost nothing to do with the temperature of the gas being observed. The amount of IR light that is absorbed by the methane is mostly determined by its quantum mechanical properties, and temperature has a negligible effect on these properties. The density of the gas will change as it gets hotter which will change the number of molecules per unit volume, but it won't change how much each molecule themselves absorb. The shape of the plume will also affect the amount of absorption as there is more gas in the middle of a plume than the outside.

Comment: Okay I'm familiar with how these cameras work (inside and out) and that the displayed "temperature" is a computed value based on brightness and assumed emissivity and not a real temperature meaasurement. In the third video there is a color scale, we can see that the sky is radiating the least thermal IR and the ground the most thermal IR. The color scale is monotonic, and the intensity recorded from the plume is higher than the background sky. *The plume is radiating*, not absorbing. Perhaps it is just hot gas not methane. Perhaps this method does not actually specifically flag methane at all!

Comment: To avoid confusion, let's not use the word thermal when referring to these images. Thermal IR imaging measures the amount of light that is emitted per unit area due to blackbody radiation. For FLIR imaging we are representing only the amount of light absorbed by a specific wavelength that is characteristic of methane. Thermal IR images would be like a grayscale image while FLIR images would be a colour filter applied to the thermal IR image. In reality, you only collect the light absorbed by methane to increase the signal-to-noise ratio rather than filter all the light afterward.

Comment: You may be confused that you can see the earth and buildings as bright objects even though we are filtering out IR light to only "see methane". We are really only looking the absorption of 3 um light which is characteristic of methane but NOT UNIQUE. IR light is absorbed by most solids and some other molecules. But it is NOT absorbed by carbon dioxide, water, carbon monoxide, etc. So you see the solids absorbing the IR light (and others) and the methane (mostly in that band)

Comment: Okay so these "thermographic cameras" (from your answer) are not being used for thermographic observations, but this range of the EM spectrum is called "thermal infrared" to distinguish it from near infrared and far infrared/microwaves. The goal of a Stack Exchange answer is not to demonstrate one's knowledge but to answer the question as asked. I've asked "How exactly thermal infrared (e.g. FLIR) cameras image methane leaks? Are they measuring a temperature difference or an emissivity difference or...?" If answer is "No, they are measuring absorption" then the images in video #3 disagree.

Comment: You are right, it was a misnomer to call them thermographic cameras. 
I've edited my answer to clarify the differences between the two and address some of your concerns about the relative contrast of different objects in the images.

Comment: Even that camera has an "Accuracy of ±1°C for temperature range 0°C to 100°C or ±2% of reading for temperature range" based on radiance within the 3.2-3.4 um band. I downloaded the three pdf files at the bottom of the page you link to, and whenever "measurement" appears, it's in reference to temperature. It seems many cameras are also recommended as optical gas imagers, and the compliance certificate says:

Comment: ..."FLIR is proud to announce its GF620, GFx320, GF320, GF300, and G300a cameras have been independently tested and deemed compliant with the EPA’s NSPS 40 CFR part 60, subpart OOOOa sensitivity standard for optical gas imaging equipment." [Understanding Optical Gas Imaging Quantification](https://www.flir.ca/discover/instruments/gas-detection/understanding-optical-gas-imaging-quantification/) links to [1](http://docs.wixstatic.com/ugd/5922b2_0b8501e272274446a9aceda959ff5565.pdf), [2](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10962247.2016.1244130?journalCode=uawm20) and...

Comment: [3](https://www.concawe.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/rpt_17-2.pdf) and a temperature difference between the ambient environment and the leaking gas is alway essential for detection and certainly for any kind of quantitative measurement. Okay I think we're converging on an answer. The material must have some absorbance in the wavelength range of the camera (for other non-hydrocarbon gasses they use 7-8.5 or 9.5-12 μm) but that's because anything that can absorb light in a given band can also thermally radiate there. See [Absorptivity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emissivity#Absorptivity)

Comment: Well this is weird. I'm finding some other papers that say you can get away without a difference in temperature (like I was saying) but all the actual QOGI systems say it is essential. There must be some nuance I'm missing with the operating principle of these. I'll be back to update my answer when I have unraveled the differences.

Comment: So is this an acceptable answer now?

Comment: Sorry, while it's a great answer post, I can't say that I really know the answer to "How exactly thermal infrared (e.g. FLIR) cameras image methane leaks? Are they measuring a temperature difference or an emissivity difference or...?" yet. Thus no acceptance at this time. Specifically, I can't yet resolve the apparently contradictory messages about the importance of temperature, and https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/10962247.2016.1244130?journalCode=uawm20 while long and technical-sounding, doesn't resolve the radiative transfer model (Eq. 5) wrt "RF" (Eq. 6 and on) contradiction.

Comment: Comparing to this https://www.flir.ca/discover/instruments/gas-detection/understanding-optical-gas-imaging-quantification/ which asserts the importance of a temperature difference (as does my physics intuition) between gas and background, I see two commercial companies publishing opposing views in order to sell their own products.

Comment: (I left a link the [Physics SE chat room The h-bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/62879458#62879458)